# Why does my button increment the wrong variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

very new to Javascript/jquery. I've been staring at this for a couple of days now and I can't figure it out. Out of practice I'm making a game where you distribute stats to your character. I can do the first stat, the values change and the console log shows it. However all the other buttons only increment the first stat. I know how boolean logic works, I've attempted to replicate it with what I've learned in Python and C++, but I seem to be missing something as the logic is broken or the code selects the wrong variable.

```
var PTS = 20;
var strength = 5;
var agility = 5;
var constitution = 5;

function points_append(){
    PTS = PTS - 1;
    console.log("Clicked $(#PTS_append), Total Points =", PTS);
    $("#total_points").text(PTS); 

    if ($("#PTS_append").hasClass("strength")) {
        strength = strength + 1;
        console.log("Added point to STRENGTH:", strength);
        $("#strength").text(strength);
    }

    else if ($("#PTS_append").hasClass(".agility")) {
        agility = agility + 1;
        console.log("Added point to AGILITY:", agility);
        $("#agility").text(agility);
    }
}

function points_remove(){
    PTS = PTS + 1;
    console.log("Clicked $(#PTS_remove), Total Points =", PTS);
    $("#total_points").text(PTS);

    if ($("#PTS_remove").parent("#parent_strength")) {
        strength = strength - 1;
        console.log("Removed point from STRENGTH:", strength);
        $("#strength").text(strength);
    }


    else if ($("#PTS_remove").parent("#parent_agility")) {
        agility = agility - 1;
        console.log("Removed point from AGILITY:", agility);
        $("#agility").text(agility);
    }
}
```

As you can see I've made attempts with both .parent and .hasClass among other things. Coincidentally this is my first post here, so here goes nothing. I also googled the issue back and forth but haven't arrived anywhere close to an answer. I hope someone here can help me.

EDIT: This is how the HTML looks.

```
<div class = "stats_allocation">

            <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Available PTS:</th>
                <td id = "total_points">20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id = "parent_strength">
                <th>Strength:</th> 
                <td id="strength">5</td> 
                <td>
                    <button class = "strength" id = "PTS_append" onClick="points_append()">+</button>
                    <button class = "strength" id = "PTS_remove" onClick="points_remove()">-</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id = "parent_agility">
                <th>Aglity:</th> 
                <td id="agility">5</td> 
                <td>
                    <button class = "agility" id = "PTS_append" onClick="points_append()">+</button>
                    <button class = "agility" id = "PTS_remove" onClick="points_remove()">-</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id = "parent_constitution">
                <th>Constitution:</th> 
                <td id="constitution">5</td> 
                <td>
                    <button class = "constitution" id = "PTS_append" onClick="points_append()">+</button>
                    <button class = "constitution" id = "PTS_remove" onClick="points_remove()">-</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

            </table>

        </div>
```

Comment: `.hasClass("classname")` (no `.` prefix for hasclass) - `$("#x").parent("..")` will give a jquery object so using `if` on it makes no sense, maybe you meant ``$("#x").parent("..").length > 0` - but need the HTML to confirm what you're trying to check.  You might always want to look at `.closest()`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It's impossible to answer your question without much more informations, so please post a proper MCVE (cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The most important missing points here are 1/ the HTML markup and 2/ a complete explanation of what you mean by "increment the wrong variable" (IOW : what you expected to happen and what actually happens instead).

Comment: Hey, added the HTML code in question. The issue is as following. Once the character creation screen opens up, the player distributes points. The distribution of points and identifying which variable both on screen and in script are being changed is where the problem begins. My script fails to recognize and change any other variable than STRENGTH. I want it to both increment and decrement the variables in question when their corresponding buttons are pressed. Pressing the "+" button for agility should increase agility and there for not strength! I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok - in addition to the two points in the comment earlier - the other issue is that you have multiple buttons with `id=PTS_append` - so clicking the 2nd finds the 1st.  Change to `$(this).hasClass("strength")`

Comment: I suppose the more accurate question is: How do I establish my functions logic so it recognizes which buttons are being clicked and there for doesn't increment/decrement the wrong variable? EDIT: @freedomn-m will do. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: You're using `onclick=` so `this` won't work - I'll add more details in an answer.

Comment: Change the id's of your elements. Id's never should be same for any html element. Alternatively you can pass the this in funciton call and then use that in respective functions. Ex. `onClick="points_append(this)"` and then `function points_append(e){` and use that `e` as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- `id=''` can only appear once in HTML.  Using `$("#id")` will always find the first one, so you need to find the one relative to the button pressed
- `.hasClass` is used without the class indicator
- `.parent()` will only look at the node above (so for the button it will find the `td`) - you could use `.parents()` or `.closest()` - or just use the `.hasClass` as before.

As you're using `onclick=func` you can pass the button using `onclick=func(this)` and then `function fund(btn)`.

If you were using jquery `$("btn").on("click", function...` then the button would be defined as `this` for you.

Updated code:

```js
var PTS = 20;
var strength = 5;
var agility = 5;
var constitution = 5;

function points_append(btn) {
  PTS = PTS - 1;
  console.log("Clicked $(#PTS_append), Total Points =", PTS);
  $("#total_points").text(PTS);

  if ($(btn).hasClass("strength")) {
    strength = strength + 1;
    console.log("Added point to STRENGTH:", strength);
    $("#strength").text(strength);
  } else if ($(btn).hasClass("agility")) {
    agility = agility + 1;
    console.log("Added point to AGILITY:", agility);
    $("#agility").text(agility);
  }
}

function points_remove(btn) {
  PTS = PTS + 1;
  console.log("Clicked $(#PTS_remove), Total Points =", PTS);
  $("#total_points").text(PTS);

  if ($(btn).closest("#parent_strength").length > 0) {
    strength = strength - 1;
    console.log("Removed point from STRENGTH:", strength);
    $("#strength").text(strength);
  } else if ($(btn).closest("#parent_agility").length > 0) {
    agility = agility - 1;
    console.log("Removed point from AGILITY:", agility);
    $("#agility").text(agility);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stats_allocation">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Available PTS:</th>
      <td id="total_points">20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="parent_strength">
      <th>Strength:</th>
      <td id="strength">5</td>
      <td>
        <button class="strength" onClick="points_append(this)">+</button>
        <button class="strength" onClick="points_remove(this)">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="parent_agility">
      <th>Aglity:</th>
      <td id="agility">5</td>
      <td>
        <button class="agility" onClick="points_append(this)">+</button>
        <button class="agility" onClick="points_remove(this)">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="parent_constitution">
      <th>Constitution:</th>
      <td id="constitution">5</td>
      <td>
        <button style='display:none;' class="constitution" onClick="points_append(this)">+</button>
        <button style='display:none;' class="constitution" onClick="points_remove(this)">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

To make this more 'jquery-y' (and to appease the purists), don't add event handlers in the html, updated snippet:

```js
$("button.add").on("click", points_append);
$("button.remove").on("click", points_remove);

var PTS = 20;
var strength = 5;
var agility = 5;
var constitution = 5;

function points_append() {
  PTS = PTS - 1;
  console.log("Clicked $(#PTS_append), Total Points =", PTS);
  $("#total_points").text(PTS);

  if ($(this).hasClass("strength")) {
    strength = strength + 1;
    console.log("Added point to STRENGTH:", strength);
    $("#strength").text(strength);
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("agility")) {
    agility = agility + 1;
    console.log("Added point to AGILITY:", agility);
    $("#agility").text(agility);
  }
}

function points_remove(btn) {
  PTS = PTS + 1;
  console.log("Clicked $(#PTS_remove), Total Points =", PTS);
  $("#total_points").text(PTS);

  if ($(this).closest("#parent_strength").length > 0) {
    strength = strength - 1;
    console.log("Removed point from STRENGTH:", strength);
    $("#strength").text(strength);
  } else if ($(this).closest("#parent_agility").length > 0) {
    agility = agility - 1;
    console.log("Removed point from AGILITY:", agility);
    $("#agility").text(agility);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stats_allocation">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Available PTS:</th>
      <td id="total_points">20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="parent_strength">
      <th>Strength:</th>
      <td id="strength">5</td>
      <td>
        <button class="strength add">+</button>
        <button class="strength remove">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="parent_agility">
      <th>Aglity:</th>
      <td id="agility">5</td>
      <td>
        <button class="agility add">+</button>
        <button class="agility remove">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

There are other improvements that could be made such as using an object for your abilities and a single method to add/remove any attribute (by defining the attribute on the button container) which will greatly reduce your code and make it more reusable.  But it's a good start.

Comment: Thank you! I've wasted so much time trying to figure this out. I've learned more here than during the hours spent trying to Google all my issues. I'm glad I signed up to this website now.